# Is there any way to know if a facebook user has email before to be signedUp in firebase?

Tags: facebook, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

We are working on an Ionic app where we use firebase and we allow users to login with facebook.
We decided that the email is a required field for our database.

We are facing that some facebook users don't have an email in her/his account (because they created the account using a phone number, for example).

Currently we know the user data after the user is signed up. Is there any way to know that information before that?

```js
  signIanWithFacebook() {
    return this.facebook.login(['email']).then(res => {
      const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
      // here is where we would like to know if user has email
      firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(facebookCredential)
        .then(
          // here is where we currently know if the user has email or not
          (userCred: firebase.auth.UserCredential) => this.handleSocialMediaLogin(userCred)
        ).catch((err) => this.onLoginError(err));
    });
  }
```

Comment: The user needs to sign in to Facebook and grant your app permission before you can know if they have an email at Facebook.

Comment: That's what I thought. I just wondered if there was any way to know it before or doing something similar. Thanks anyway @WizKid .